# Audio file uploaded to Firebase Storage via Android cannot be played

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload voice note to Firebase Storage with this code:

```
private void UploadAudio(String mFilename, String key){

        StorageReference reference= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()


        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mFileName));

        StorageMetadata metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
                .setContentType("audio/mp3")
                .build();

        Log.d("AUDIOUPLOADER", "File to upload: "+mFileName);
        Log.d("AUDIOUPLOADER", "Firebase path: "+key+".mp3");

        reference.child("Audio").child(key+".mp3").putFile(uri, metadata).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {


                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
```

When running the code, I see these lines at logcat

```
2022-01-31 01:52:36.685 19814-19814/com.xyz.testapp D/AUDIOUPLOADER: File to upload: /storage/emulated/0/audiorecordtest.mp3
2022-01-31 01:52:36.685 19814-19814/com.xyz.testapp D/AUDIOUPLOADER: Firebase path: -MugKEi8VPrFldLbRqVq.mp3
```

**/storage/emulated/0/audiorecordtest.mp3** can be played normally with Total Commander, and the size is 9.4 KB

Then I tried to inspect **MugKEi8VPrFldLbRqVq.mp3** at Firebase Storage page. The size is also 9.4 KB. And when I clicked it, a media player was shown on Chrome but the duration is 0:00. It couldn't be played. What's wrong here?

Comment: 9.4 KB is not precise. Every byte counts. Tell size in bytes to compare.

Comment: Also download the file and play on the same device.